# onclick multiple elements in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a feature to hide and show description of image thumbnails (if user click the image thumbnail, the description will be shown animated). I already followed tutorial in VueJS about transition but unfortunately only one thumbnail works and the rest don't. I already removed the script during my `try and errors`. So, let take script of jquery as an example (pseudo code since I can't recall jquery syntax for now):

```
<div id="app">
   <p> 1 </p>
   <p> 2 </p>
</div>

jQuery("#app p").click(function(){
      alert(p.text);
   });
```

We only need that script and `alert(p.text)` has different value based on which `<p>` that user clicked and we dont need to write script for each `<p>`

How to do it in VueJS ? in nutshell I am confused how to apply one instance of VueJS with click event on it for many elements.

Comment: Share live demo or any fiddle ? In your given code there is no vuejs involved

Comment: sorry i dont have any fiddle. I hope that jQuery script explains what i am trying to do. in nutshell i am confused how to apply one instance of vue js for many elements.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want like this

```js
var V = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    items:[
      {name:'Test1',desc:'test1 Desc',show:false},
      {name:'Test2',desc:'test2 Desc',show:false},
      {name:'Test3',desc:'test3 Desc',show:false},
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.7/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in items">
    <span @click="item.show = !item.show">{{item.name}}</span>
    <span class="" v-if="item.show">: {{item.desc}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this code and combine with transition guide in vue js. thank you! i will be back again if i stuck. thank you

Comment: what if vue has no idea how many child elements (items) ? i mean the span elements has rendered via conventional way (loop from php) not from loop from an array javascript.

Comment: share what data you have from php  ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/166b65b7b03f982bac25f8498c64c77a ignore this part ` @click="showDetail"`. that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="item in numbers" @click="fun(item)">{{item}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      numbers:[1,2,3,4,5]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    fun:function(number){
      alert(number);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I's different between MVC and MVVM.

Comment: yes. it's harder than jQuery and more complicated. jQuery can solve this problem with only few scripts and more faaaaar easier. or jQuery and Vue js was created for different purpose?

Comment: What if the array contain 10000 numbers?Some easy demos shouldn't use VUE, but when your code are more complex, a MVVM framework will help you a lot. And I think this framework's best contribution is separating front and rear ends, so front-end engineer could do more things than past.