# How to use v-on:click to change multiple content - Vuejs and Liquid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify

I would like to change text and image when I click on a button, I had tried this but I get stuck and I don't know how to use it to change multiple elements,

```js
{% for variant in product.variants %}
<label for="variant_{{- variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - <img src="{{ variant.image | img_url: '100x100' }}" v-on:click="changeMessage('{{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}')"></label>
<input type="radio" {% if forloop.first %}checked{% endif %} class="variant_id" id="variant_{{- variant.id }}" name="productVariants" value="{{ variant.id }}"/>

<div class="variant_price d-none">{{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</div>
<div class="variant_sku d-none">{{ variant.sku }}</div>
<div class="variant_img d-none">{{ variant.image | img_url: master }}</div>
{% endfor %}

{% raw %}{{ price }}{% endraw %}
{% raw %}{{ image }}{% endraw %}
```

[Current look on the store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojyJa.png)

The price is now showing by default I have to click the radio button to show the price, I want it to be shown by default,

[This is how it looks like after I click on the radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faoL5.png)

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
       price: document.getElementsByClassName('variant_price').innerHTML,
       sku: document.getElementsByClassName('variant_sku').innerHTML,
       img: document.getElementsByClassName('variant_img').innerHTML,
    }
  },
  methods:  {
    changeMessage(message) {
      this.message = message
    }
  },
}
```

I want when I click on the radio button it gives me the price and image, my skills on JS is so bad, please I need help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onclick multiple elements in vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406738/onclick-multiple-elements-in-vue-js)

Comment: Your approach to pass data from liquid to Vue is not good. Now you pass via class name. The backend & frontend are mixed together. 

You should construct a js variant object with liquid loops. After that, you can loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **mounted()** hook to set your defaults.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
       price: document.getElementsByClassName('variant_price').innerHTML,
       sku: document.getElementsByClassName('variant_sku').innerHTML,
       img: document.getElementsByClassName('variant_img').innerHTML,
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    //set default here, like this
    this.changeMessage(message);  
  }
  methods:  {
    changeMessage(message) {
      this.message = message
    }
  },
}
```

Also, could you elaborate it a little bit more so that I can help you in this regard

Comment: Got it, I want when I click on the button change text and image at the same time, how to do that?

Comment: @Elkazi Try to pass the index of item or item directly to the function when you click the button. and change the text and image in the function (from the index/item that you passed)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change another element using v-on:click on a button you should add to these elements a parameter `ref="nameOfRef"` and then select them in the method you called on the v-on:click like: `this.$refs.nameOfRef`

Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

    <main id="vue-app">
      
      <div ref="div">Hello world</div>
      <button type="button" v-on:click="hideElements()">Hide!</button>
      <button type="button" v-on:click="showElements()">Show!</button>
        
    </main>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#vue-app",
        methods: {

            hideElements: function () {
                this.$refs.div.style.display = "none";
            },
            showElements: function () {
                this.$refs.div.style.display = "inherit";
                
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```